# In Laravel Schema Builder, is using after() method with a database rather than MySQL will cause an error?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, laravel

In "Adding Columns" section, Laravel 4.2 [schema documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns) says:

> #### Using After On MySQL
>
> If you are using the MySQL database, you may use the after method to specify the order of columns:
>
> ```
> $table->string('column_name')->after('email');
> ```

My question: If I used to use this code and now I've decided to switch to a database rather than `MySQL` like `PostgreSQL` or `SQL Server`, is this code will cause an error when switching to the new database? Should I write it like this instead to avoid any errors?

```
    if (Config::get('database')['default'] === 'mysql'){
        $table->string('column_name')->after('email');
    } else {
        $table->string('column_name');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't cause an error. It'll just insert it at the end.

No need for your own conditional.

Comment: Can confirm this, I just played with SQLite for local dev the other day and it happily ignored my `after` calls.